# Function only working properly with $('#element').click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jQuery to call PHP script with two parameters, from and to, which are used to query MySQL with a limit between the two. Im building a pagnition-thing.

The problem is that this works properly using this:

```
$(document.ready(function(){

   function display_from_server(){
      from = calculate_from_value(); // first run 0, second run 11, third run 22 ...
      to = calculate_to_value();  // first run 10, second run 21, third run 32 ...

      //.. sends 0 and 10 to server and display response on screen.
   }

   $('#button').click(function(){
     display_from_server();
   });
});
```

But changing it to this it doesnt work anymore:

```
$(document.ready(function(){

   function display_from_server(){
      from = calculate_from_value(); // first run 0, second run 11, third run 22 ...
      to = calculate_to_value();  // first run 10, second run 21, third run 32 ...

      //.. supposed to send 0 and 10 to server, but sends 0 and 0 ! ?
   }

   display_from_server();

});
```

So when calling as a callback function for a button click, it works, but calling it directly dont work! in FF the rest of the page loads except the data from the server. In Chrome only the background loads! Whata heck is wrong... ?

Comment: You have a typo at `$(document.ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how much it matters, but I would put the function outside of the `$(document).ready(`.

```
function display_from_server() {
   from = calculate_from_value(); // first run 0, second run 11, third run 22 ...
   to = calculate_to_value();  // first run 10, second run 21, third run 32 ...
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    display_from_server();   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the first line to this:

```
//JQuery adds the "ready" method to the document object
$(document).ready(function(){
  //rest of the code
});
```

I'm surprised it worked at all since the call to document.ready in your example should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a breakpoint in side calculate_to_value() in the second case and make sure the stuff its calculating from is actually ready right when $(document).ready first runs

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `calculate_to_value()` has a bug. Some ideas:

1. Check the JavaScript error console. Maybe an exception was thrown
2. Add some log statements to `calculate_to_value()`
3. What happens if you replace `calculate_to_value()` with `from+10`?